# Unix timestamp in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite, timestamp, unix-timestamp

How do you obtain the current timestamp in Sqlite? current_time, current_date, current_timestamp both return formatted dates, instead of a long.

```
sqlite> insert into events (timestamp) values (current_timestamp);
sqlite> insert into events (timestamp) values (current_date);
sqlite> insert into events (timestamp) values (current_time);
sqlite> select * from events;
1|2010-09-11 23:18:38
2|2010-09-11
3|23:18:51
```

What I want:

```
4|23234232
```

Answer (score 134, accepted):

The [docs](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) mention this method:

```
SELECT strftime('%s', 'now');
1284248196
```

And this one which includes the fractional part:

```
SELECT (julianday('now') - 2440587.5) * 86400.0;
1284248196.65098
```

Both represent [Unix Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), the number of seconds passed since January 1, 1970.

Comment: Still handy info after 10 years!

Comment: The first one may need casting to a number before numeric comparisons! For example, a quick and dirty `1*strftime('%s', 'now')` might be enough, or you can use the proper `CAST( strftime('%s', 'now') AS INT )` syntax.

Answer (score 3):

SQLite now has `unixepoch` function that returns a unix timestamp (https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

However right now I don't recommend it because some things like Sqlitebrowser and Entity Framework (6.0.8) don't seem to support it yet. Right now it's still better to use old `strftime` from accepted answer

Comment: More specifically "That command wasn't added until 3.38 (2022-02-22)." (see https://sqlite.org/forum/forumpost/5f8af1c00129da37)

Comment: The correct way to do now, is `unixepoch('now')`

Answer (score 0):

```
select strftime('%W'),date('now'),date(),datetime(),strftime('%s', 'now');
```

result in

```
strftime('%W')  -   date('now')  -  date()   -  datetime()   -     strftime('%s', 'now')
    08       -      2021-02-23   -  2021-02-23 - 2021-02-23  15:35:12-  1614094512
```